# WP7: Build and use own DatePickerPage

Tags: windows-phone-7, silverlight-toolkit

As far as I understand understand the DatePicker control in the WP7 Controls Toolkit, it opens a DatePickerPage to let you select the date for the control.

I need such a page directly in my app, without the picker control first. Ideally my page would have an additional "today" button, that resets the weels to the current date.

How can I build this? Should I derive from DatePickerPage or DateTimePickerPageBase? How can I call the page (I tried to navigate to the DatePickerPage with NavigationService.Navigate, but I got an NullReferenceException) and get/set the date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, now I got it. I can manually navigate to the `DatePickerPage`, but I have to assign the date to the value of the page in the `Navigated` event:

```
void dialogFrame_Navigated(object sender, System.Windows.Navigation.NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
    IDateTimePickerPage page = e.Content as IDateTimePickerPage;
    if (page != null)
    {
        page.Value = myDate;
    }
}
```